# Using a std::ostringstream in an exception

Tags: c++, exception

I'm just wondering why I am getting an error in the following program.  `ExcepParam` builds but `ExcepParamOss` doesn't.  Is there something special about `ostringstream` that stops its `.str()` from being accessed by a `const` function?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// This compiles
class ExcepParam: public std::exception
{
    std::string ehs;
public:
    ExcepParam(int in_value)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "ExcepParam: " << in_value;
        ehs = oss.str();
    }

    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return ehs.c_str();
    }
};

// This does not compile
class ExcepParamOss: public std::exception
{
    std::stringstream oss;
public:
    ExcepParamOss(int in_value)
    {
        oss << "ExceptParamOss: " << in_value;
    }

    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return oss.str().c_str();  // I'm guessing the error is here
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw ExcepParam(356);
    }
    catch (ExcepParam& e)
    {
        const char* msg = e.what();
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }

    try
    {
        throw ExcepParamOss(356);
    }
    catch (ExcepParamOss& e)
    {
        const char* msg = e.what();
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting on VS2010 is

```
  ExcepTest.cpp
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sstream(724): error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
          ]
          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ios(176) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios'
          with
          [
              _Elem=char, 
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
          ]
          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 
'std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)'
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
          ]
```

Comment: 2 Things: (1)  `return oss.str().c_str();` returning the address of a temporary object (is UB) and (2) otherwise clean compile live https://godbolt.org/z/zE6dvq

Comment: 3rd thing: (off by 1 error) just seen your compiler version note that VS2010 is not fully C++11

Comment: Is there a reason why these classes are not deriving from [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)? It already implements `what()` for you, just pass its constructor your desired `string`, eg: `class ExcepParam: public std::runtime_error { public: ExcepParam(int in_value) : std::runtime_error("ExcepParam: " + std::to_string(in_value)) { } };`

Comment: I was trying to get to the bottom of why having oss as a member variable didn't compile, even if it was mutable.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am  aware that VS2010 isn't fully C++11.  My VS2019 which it originally failed on was still updating so I just went to an XP VM which had VS2010 which came up with the same failure.